# object has no attribute session

Tags: python, django

I am creating a checkin/checkout application for inventory. The users do not need a password or email and only need to enter a number or scan a card with their barcode. So instead of using the auth / users model, I am using my own called `Members`. Eveything works fine, I can login / logout but the issue starts when I try to checkout an item. I then get an error `Member object has no attribute 'session'`

How do I resolve this error?

**ERROR**

```
[27/Mar/2013 12:16:30] ERROR [django.request:215] Internal Server Error: /checkout/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/Google Drive/Python/GearTracker/GearTracker/decorators.py", line 15, in wrapper
    return function(request, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/username/Google Drive/Python/GearTracker/inventory/views.py", line 28, in checkout
    check_status = check_in_out_item(request.session.get('user'),checked_out_item)
  File "/Users/username/Google Drive/Python/GearTracker/GearTracker/decorators.py", line 12, in wrapper
    if not (request.session.get('is_authed') == True):
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'session'
```

**decorators.py**

```
def is_user_authed(function):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kw):
        logger.info(request)
        if not (request.session.get('is_authed') == True):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
        else:
            return function(request, *args, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

**inventory/views.py snippet**

```
@is_user_authed
def checkout(request):
    form = CheckoutForm(request.POST or None)
    logger.info(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if (request.POST.get('serial')):
            try:
                checked_out_item = Inventory.objects.get(serial=request.POST.get('serial'))
                check_status = check_in_out_item(request.session.get('user'),checked_out_item)
            except Inventory.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        elif (request.POST.get('barcode')):
            try:
                checked_out_item = Inventory.objects.get(barcode=request.POST.get('barcode'))
                check_status = check_in_out_item(request.session.get('user'),checked_out_item)
            except Inventory.DoesNotExist:
                pass

    checked_out_items = Checkout.objects.all().filter(user=request.session.get('user'),checked_in__isnull=True)

    return render(request, 'inventory/index.html', {'items': checked_out_items, 'form': form})
```

**inventory models**

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    p_number = models.BigIntegerField()
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Inventory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Active (can be checked out if not out for repair)",blank=True,default=True)
    repair = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Out for repair?",blank=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Checkout(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Inventory)
    checked_out = models.DateTimeField()
    checked_in = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item.name
```

**MIDDLEWARE**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L44

Comment: What else have you decorated with `is_user_authed`?  My bet is you have that decorator on `check_in_out_item` as well.  I can't see another reason for your callstack to be recursing back in to the decorator from the view.

Comment: Umm, Looks strange, Are you sure you have `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES list in settings.py?

Comment: @dm03514 I cannot use this as I am technically not logging the user in but just checking if the p_number they provided is in the database and marking the session as logged in. I am not using the User model so that won't work.

Comment: @MostafaR Yes, I have included my middleware in my OP

Comment: Why you don't want to use django's authentication system? You can `login`/`logout` users without using `authenticate` function.

Comment: @MostafaR because I don't want to have to create passwords and usernames for accounts. I don't need them.

Comment: @sr2222 Yes I have it on all my inventory methods in the inventory view.py, including `check_in_out_item`

Comment: Well, that's the problem then.  You are going back in to the decorator, but the view is passing `request.session.get('user')`, which I assume is a `Member` object, in as the first argument to `check_in_out_item`, which is decorated and thus expects a `Request` object.  Either pull the decorator off `check_in_out_item` or pass the `request` directly to it instead of the user.

Comment: @sr2222 that was it! ty! For some reason this was working before when I was using the built in auth system but when I switched over to my own, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the problem is that `check_in_out_item` is expecting a `Request` since you've decorated it, but you are passing it `user`, which is a `Member`.  You need to modify `check_in_out_item` to accept a `Request` instead of a `Member` or remove the decorator.