# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'session' " when override SignupForm in django allauth app

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-allauth

I tried to implement django **allauth** app with **SignupForm** *override*, my code almost works when entering data into the signup form and saves users, but after save, I redirected to a new page that showed me `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'session'` AttributeError.
How can I fix it?

## *urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import login, logout, AllauthSignUpView

app_name = 'register'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', login, name='login'),
    path('signup/', AllauthSignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('logout/', logout, name='logout'),
]
```

## *views.py*

override SignupView As follows as:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from .form import AllauthLoginForm, AllauthSignUpForm
from allauth.account.views import SignupView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class AllauthSignUpView(SignupView):
    template_name = 'register/signup.html'
    form_class = AllauthSignUpForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('core:home')  #Redirect to home.html

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form.clean()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('core:home')   #Redirect to home.html
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AllauthSignUpView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        signUpForm = AllauthSignUpForm(self.request.POST or None)
        context['form'] = signUpForm
        return context
```

## *form.py*

override SignupForm As follows as:

```
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm, SignupForm
from django import forms

class AllauthSignUpForm(SignupForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AllauthSignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'] = forms.CharField(
            label='',
            widget=forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'signup_name_inp text-right mb-4 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0',
                    'placeholder': 'نام کاربری',
                    'dir': 'rtl',
                }
            ),
        )
        self.fields['email'] = forms.EmailField(
            label='',
            widget=forms.EmailInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'signup_mail_inp text-right mb-4 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0',
                    'placeholder': 'ایمیل (اختیاری)',
                    'dir': 'rtl',
                }
            )
        )
        self.fields['password1'] = forms.CharField(
            label='',
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'signup_pass_inp1 text-right mb-4 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0',
                    'placeholder': 'کلمه عبور',
                    'dir': 'rtl',
                }
            )
        )
        self.fields['password2'] = forms.CharField(
            label='',
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'signup_pass_inp2 text-right mb-4 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0',
                    'placeholder': 'تکرار کلمه عبور',
                    'dir': 'rtl'
                }
            )
        )
    def save(self, request=None):
        # Ensure you call the parent class's save.
        # .save() returns a User object.
        user = super(AllauthSignUpForm, self).save(request)

        # Add your own processing here.
        print(user.username)
        # You must return the original result.
        return user
```

## *signup.html*

```
          <form dir='rtl' class="text-right border-0 p-5  bg-transparent" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'register:signup' %}" >
            {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form|crispy }}
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-info  btn-block z-depth-0 my-4 waves-effect rounded-pill" type="submit">{% trans "ثبت نام" %} &raquo;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                  <p class="float-right  mt-3" >آیا اکانت ساخته اید؟ <a class="font-weight-bold" href="{% url 'register:login' %}" style="color: #858585 !important;">وارد شوید</a>.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

## *settings.py*

```
ACCOUNTS_FORMS = {
    'login': 'registerations.form.AllauthLoginForm',
    'signup': 'registerations.form.AllauthSignUpForm',
    'add_email': 'allauth.account.forms.AddEmailForm',
    'change_password': 'allauth.account.forms.ChangePasswordForm',
    'set_password': 'allauth.account.forms.SetPasswordForm',
    'reset_password': 'allauth.account.forms.ResetPasswordForm',
    'reset_password_from_key': 'allauth.account.forms.ResetPasswordKeyForm',
    'disconnect': 'allauth.socialaccount.forms.DisconnectForm',
}
```

There are some useful link below:
[help-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667744/object-has-no-attribute-session)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There look to be a few potential issues with your code but the main one that's likely causing your stated issue is that you're not passing the `request` object to your `form.save()` call in your `views.py` file.

It should look something more like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):

    # Don't do this. form_valid() only gets called on a valid form anyway
    # if form.is_valid():

    form.save(self.request)

    # No need to call form.clean() again, especially after already saving the form
    # form.clean()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('core:home')   #Redirect to home.html
```

So, in summary, you don't really seem to be doing anything "custom" in your custom `form_valid()` function, so you're probably better off completely removing it and just using the one defined in the parent class.  You've already specified your `success_url` so you can let allauth's `form_valid()` do the work for you.